# In Mongoose How to exclude documents that have common value in particular field but return first document only?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, filter, nosql

I need to exclude the documents that have a common value in a given field but need to get a single document

let me explain

```
{
name : "David",
"msg" : "Hi how are you",
"createdBy: "1234"
},
{
name : "Robert",
"msg" : "Hi Fine are you",
"createdBy: "1234"
},
{
name : "donald",
"msg" : "Hi Enjoyinh are you",
"createdBy: "7890"
},
{
name : "dani",
"msg" : "Hi playing are you",
"createdBy: "7890"
}
```

If you look the above documents ...

The field `createdBy` having two duplicate value 1234 & 7890

I need a query that return like this

```
   {
    name : "David",
    "msg" : "Hi how are you",
    "createdBy: "1234"
    },
    {
    name : "donald",
    "msg" : "Hi Enjoyinh are you",
    "createdBy: "7890"
    },
```

That is , if a field have same value in collection , only a single document if that have to be returned .

How to achieve this in mongoose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) for grouping same values, and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) for replace grouped documents from `$group`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // updated match/where conditions
  {
    $match: {
      isRead: false, 
      isChat: true, 
      receiverBy: userId
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$createdBy",
      root: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$root"
    }
  }
])
```

Working Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/qzyXuP-3nv8

Comment: How to add you query long with this existing query on Schema --->

Comment: Notification.count({ isRead: false, isChat: true, receiverBy: userId })

Comment: I want to add your query to above query .. How ?

Comment: not getting you, what is notification and count? what exactly you want?

Comment: To be simple , In your aggregate query I need to include this filters also  :: isRead: false, isChat: true, receiverBy: userId

Comment: means this filters for where/match right? if this and this fields match with particular document then matched records will return?

Comment: Sorry .. I actually followed an another way that completely    avoided this flow .. So I no longer need it. So I forget that i asked this question  ... But your solution  worked perfectly ... thanks